# ES6 when to use String.raw over default template literal

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to concatenate a bunch of strings to build a query string in Javascript. Previously I have achieved this through ugly string concatenation:

```
var queryString = "?action=" + actionValue + "&data=" + dataValue";
```

But with ES6 I see that there are new methods provided that could help me achieve the same result with much nicer looking code, like *string interpolation in C# 6:*

```
string s = $"action={actionValue}&data={dataValue}"
```

I have tested with both default template literal and `String.raw` and although the syntax for each is slightly different, they both work. I'm leaning towards using `String.raw` in my final copy as it doesn't allow for the string to be tagged and thus tinkered with in the future like the default template literal does.

Although it does say in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Raw_strings) that `String.raw` basically calls the default template literal method but I like the syntax of `String.raw` better... I am calling the `String.join` method inside the curly braces of my string that I am formatting so maybe that is a misuse of `String.raw`.

Are any ES6 wizards out there able to enlighten me and provide reasons for one over the other?

My code:

```
var defaultTemplateStringUrl = `@Url.Action("DownloadMultiple")?inIds=${inData.join(',')}&outIds=${outData.join(',')}&truckId=${truckId}`;
var rawStringUrl = String.raw `@Url.Action("DownloadMultiple")?inIds=${inData.join(',')}&outIds=${outData.join(',')}&truckId=${truckId}`;

window.open( /*url goes here*/);
```

Comment: How exactly are you using `String.raw`? Are you calling it as a function? That seems inconvenient.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question. Can't you just do `var queryString = \`?action=${actionValue}&data=${dataValue}\`;`?

Comment: Why would you want raw strings? All you should do is use a tag that calls `encodeURIComponent` on each interpolation value.

Comment: "*I am calling the `String.join` method inside the curly braces of my string*" - wait, what? Please just show us your code.

Comment: "doesn't allow for the string to be tagged and thus tinkered " - You can't apply a tagged template function to a String that already exists - It's a tinkering free zone.

Comment: @FelixKling No I am not using it as a function.

Comment: @David Sherret yes I can do that, I am just wondering which way would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Bergi I have added my code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using `String.raw` makes no sense for you.

You should rather write your own template tag that does the necessary URL encoding and handles arrays in a manner you like.

```
function myUrl(parts) {
    var url = parts[0];
    for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var val = arguments[i];
        if (Array.isArray(val))
            val = val.join(",");
        url += encodeURIComponent(val);
        url += parts[i];
    }
    return url;
}
```

Then you can use

```
window.open(myUrl`@Url.Action("DownloadMultiple")?inIds=${inData}&outIds=${outData}&truckId=${truckId}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bergi and others.

Comment: @FelixKling: `parts` is, `url` is a string

Comment: I somehow thought `parts === arguments`. Somehow got confused between the example on MDN and yours :P :D

Answer (score 5):

A template literal produces a string. If you use `String.raw`, you will get the raw form of that string:

```
`a\tb`;           // "a b"
String.raw`a\tb`; // "a\tb"
```

So you should use `String.raw` only when you want the raw form.

Comment: Nit: "template literal"

Comment: Ah I see, I should probably be using the template literal method then, rather than String.raw to prevent things from not being encoded properly for the URL.